# Correct association for Twitter-style posts by followed users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to list all the posts made by a user's followed users, and not sure how to correctly set up the associations. This has been discussed in various forms but I can't find a definitive answer that works in this case. My current associations are as follows:

```
user.rb:
  has_many :followers, :class_name => 'UserFollower', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :following, :class_name => 'UserFollower', :foreign_key => 'follower_id'
  has_many :posts

user_follower.rb:
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User'

post.rb
  belongs_to :user
```

I want to be able to do something like current_user.following_user_posts. So I'm trying to define an association in my user.rb something like:

```
    has_many :following_user_posts, :through => :following
```

Obviously this isn't quite right, but where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Michael hartle answers this exactly in his tutorial using his Micropost.from_users_followed_by method http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_first_feed_implementation

Comment: Thanks - yes I've seen that, but it looks like it could be a bit out of date & I'd like to do it with associations

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, seems like a simple problem but the terminology makes it quite confusing. I have the following in by user.rb:

```
  has_many :user_followers
  has_many :followers, :through => :user_followers, :source => :follower #the users that are following this user
  has_many :user_followings, :class_name => 'UserFollower',  :foreign_key => "follower_id"
  has_many :following, :through => :user_followings, :source => :user #the users that this user is following
  has_many :following_user_posts, :through => :user_followings, :source => :posts
```

And in my user_follower.rb:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :posts, :through => :user, :source => :posts
```

The resulting query uses 2 inner joins - I have no idea how well this will scale but its working fine for me on development. So now, I can simply use current_user.following_user_posts